# Dragula begin dragging on long press event

Tags: javascript, dragula

I was wondering if there is a way to begin moving the item sin dragula after a long press event. 
The situation is that I have a long list, that i need t be able to scroll and reorganize the items. I was thinking that items should be able to be moved after a long press event. 
Is there a way to do that with dragula and vanilla Javascript?

thanks, 
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Drake.destroy() sould be used for every Drake event that should not in ode the drag event.